# help me adapt the bizzy diet to my needs

Tags: weight-loss, diet, workout-routines, body-fat

This question is specifically about the [bizzy diet](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/the-bizzy-diet.html). But I guess it could pertain to any other diet.

My goal is to **lose the 8 kgs of mostly fat** I've accumulated all over my body the past year. I want to go back to the 12% body fat I had when I used to be a swimmer/cyclist.
A gist of the diet is:

- Workout A - Upper Body
- Workout B - Lower Body

And every week you do Workout A, then B then A then rest a few days.

The workouts go like this in a circuit:

- HIIT cardio 20 mins
- Some weights
- Cardio 10 mins
- Some more weights

All in a circuit.

My problem :

- I only have a pool for the Cardio
- Besides dumbells I don't have a gym.
- (I know how it sounds but unfortunately it will be this way for a month)

**My question** :

#### Exercise

Can I change it up a little where I do a resistance circuit from the [Nike Training App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nike-training-club/id301521403?mt=8), it goes like this for **30 mins**:

```
1 min light jog 
1 min high knee runs 
1 min recovery 
1 min alternating ball pushups
2 min of squat jumps
2 min ski jump to cross back lunge
...
... Final 8 mins is stretching
```

AND then immediately I go do the HIIT in the pool?
OR should I look at the Workouts and replace them with upper and lower body workouts that do no need equipment?

I already do yoga 2-4 times a week in the morning before work.

#### Diet

I know how important diet is, but here again I'm in pickle. I will have to buy cooked food from outside for some time (1-2 weeks). I have all the supplements listed.

For lunch and dinner I'll have cooked veggies (indian style, so spicy) And boiled eggs. The 9PM meal I plan to have Curd?

Could you guys evaluate whether my substitutions are sound? Will it be as effective?

Comment: For starters, the "bizzy diet" isn't really a diet, it's a workout plan. And for food, I would ditch the supplements and eat real food. Right now your diet consists of mixed veggies, eggs and supplements? That's crap.

Comment: @john What would you suggest ?

Comment: Real food. There is tons of information available, but lean meats, fruits/veggies, carbs with as little processing as possible, healthy fats/oils. Pretty much any diet plan with a "name" (south beach, paleo, pritikin, atkins, etc etc) isn't a sustainable, long term solution.

Comment: @john true. I do want to learn how to cook my own healthier meals, and change my lifestyle. However I'm looking at this diet more as a kick starter. I've spent the whole of last year losing my health, going from super athletic cyclist/swimmer to flab and fat. I'm still currently in a situation where I can't cook meals yet (I barely have a home) but I want to start by not being fat anymore. So I'm looking at more a jump starter kind of thing.

Comment: Ps: I am including fruits and some carbs. (Whole wheat bread).

Comment: Oh, I'd also suggest editing your post to include what you specifically want to achieve. There may be another program (Such as stronglifts or similar) that may be a better fit, but in any case we can't suggest edits to a program if we don't know what your after.

Comment: @johnp done :) I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gideon, 
 As mentioned in the comments above, the Bizzy Diet isn't really a diet program; it's a quick fitness program *(unlike Insanity or P90X);* the main difference is that it guarantees result in 21 days.

### Nutrition

While cooking is recommended *(because it's cheaper and you have more control)*, you are free to purchase cooked meals. Even some fast food restaurants are offering health-conscious meals now. There are low-calorie chicken wraps from Chick Fila *(about 250 calories, I believe)* and some healthy burgers from Wendys *(about 400 calories).* You can also purchase home-style meals from other restaurants as well as visit health-conscious restaurants for their options. 
 
The biggest problem you'll have with these pre-cooked options is the quantity of sodium. Most of them are high in salt, so you have to watch out for them. Your current food choices consist of only vegetables and fruits; you need lots of protein too. So basically, your food choices should consist of at least protein and fiber. Eggs, cereal, milk, turkey, chicken, etc are options you can look into. But yes, you can modify the food to match what is currently available to you.

### Exercises

Most of the exercises in **Workout A** are exercises you can do in your living room; you don't need a gym to accomplish them. Since you already have dumbbells, you can use them instead of barbells. If you happen to have a pullup bar *(which you can get at Walmart for about $30 or less)*, you can perform all the remaining presses. Just ensure you workout on a mat, carpet or something soft so you don't apply too much pressure to your joints. 
 
You don't need a pool for the cardio *(although you can use it too)*; **run**. You can run around the neighborhood, up and down stairs, or just in a single room. No treadmill is needed. 
 
Workout B mainly uses your body weight and some light dumbbells, which you already have. You can do those as well without additional equipment. 
 
If you're afraid of the intensity, ***go at your own pace and take breaks.*** Unless you have health issues that might prevent you from performing the program, you have everything *(and can get the rest)* to perform the exercises almost as recommended. 

 
In the end, your goal is to lose the weight, not complete some program. And adjusting programs into something that fits your schedule and capacity will help you much more than following it strictly. 
 
The only option you don't have is ***not working out.***
 
***Now, go burn some goo*** :).